# If every left coset of $H$ is a right coset the show that $H=aHa^{-1}$ for all a in G

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$H$ is a subgroup of G.

My attempt: $ha=ah' $ for every $h\in H$, where $h'\in H$ doesn't necessarily equal to $h$. So for each $h\in H$, $h=ah'a^{-1}\in aHa^{-1}$, so $H\subseteq aHa^{-1}$. Then how to show that $aHa^{-1}\subseteq H$?(from Herstein's abstract algebra Ch.2 Sec.4 problem 8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $aga^{-1}$ for $g\in H$ arbitrary. Then $ag\in aH=Ha$, so $ag=g^{\prime}a$ for some $g^{\prime}\in H$. Hence, $aga^{-1}=g^{\prime}$, and we get the result you need, that $aHa^{-1}\subseteq H$.

You should realise that this all implies that the given condition implies that the subgroup $H$ is a *normal subgroup* of $G$.

A different idea to the proof you are proposing would be to simply note the following.
$$aHa^{-1}=H\Leftrightarrow aHa^{-1}a=Ha\Leftrightarrow aH=Ha$$
This is slicker, but I understand why you would not necessarily be comfortable with it.

(***Small point***: You write $\subseteq$, as if the things we are dealing with are just subsets. However, they are subgroups, so $\leq$ would be more appropriate. **Challenge**: Prove what I just said, that $aHa^{-1}\leq G$ for all $H\leq G$ and all $a\in G$.)

Comment: $aHa^{-1}=H$, and $H\subseteq G$, so $aHa^{-1}\subseteq G$? (Forgive me for using $\subseteq$ because i don't know how to type that notation )

Comment: Use `\leq`. What you said only holds in this very specific case (when $H$ is a normal subgroup). However, for example, the subgroup $H=\langle e, (1, 2)\rangle$ of $S_3$ is not a normal subgroup of $S_3$ but this result does still hold.

Comment: I know, for every $h\in H$, by closure of G, $aha^{-1}$, therefore $aHa^{-1}\subset G$. For $\forall  aha^{-1}$,$ah^{-1}a^{-1}\in aHa^{-1}$ since $H$ is a subgroup. For any two $aha^{-1},ah'a^{-1}$, their product $ahh'a^{-1}\in aHa^{-1}$ since $H$ is a group.

Comment: Hmm. Your writing looks slightly confused. You just need to show that if $aha^{-1}\in aHa$ then $(aha^{-1})^{-1}\in aHa$, and that if $aha^{-1}, ah^{\prime}a^{-1}\in aHa^{-1}$ then $aha^{-1}ah^{\prime}a^{-1}\in aHa^{-1}$. So, what is $(aha^{-1})^{-1}$? And what is $aha^{-1}ah^{\prime}a^{-1}$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $a\in G$ and $H$ be a subgroup in which every left coset of $H$ is equal to some right coset $H$. Let $x\in H^a\Rightarrow axa^{-1}\in H\Rightarrow ax=(axa^{-1})a\in Ha=bH
\Rightarrow ax=bh, h\in H\Rightarrow x=a^{-1}bh (*)$.

Since $a\in Ha, a\in bH\Rightarrow \exists h'\in H$ such that $a=bh'\Rightarrow e=a^{-1}bh' (**)$.

From (*), $x=a^{-1}bh$ implies $xh^{-1}=a^{-1}b$. From (**), $xh^{-1}h'=a^{-1}bh'=e
\Rightarrow x=(h')^{-1}h\in H\Rightarrow H^a\subseteq H$.

Now, let $x\in H$. Still assume that $aH=bH$. Then $a\in aH$ implies $
a\in Hb\Rightarrow a=hb, h\in H\Rightarrow h^{-1}=ba^{-1} (***)$. Now, $ax\in aH$ (why?). Then $ax\in Hb\Rightarrow ax=h'b, h'\in H\Rightarrow axa^{-1}=h'ba^{-1}\Rightarrow (h')^{-1}axa^{-1}=ba^{-1}=h^{-1}$ by (***). Then $axa^{-1}=h'h^{-1}\in H\Rightarrow x\in H^a\Rightarrow H\subseteq H^a\Rightarrow H$ is normal.