# A sufficient condition of normality for a subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be a group and let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$.  Assume that for every element $x$ of $G$ , there exists an element $y$ of $G$ such that $xH=Hy$.
Show that $H$ is **normal** in $G$.

Actually, here I have some ideas but I am not sure whether they are true or not.

$xH=Hy$

$xH y^-1 = H$

$xHy^-1 x = Hx$

if we can  show that $y^{-1}x$ is element of $H$ it will be proved , but this is just a guess.

or simply if we can show $x=y$ it will be also helpful.

And, another of my approach is that if for every $x$ is element of $G$ there exist an element $y$ of G means $x$ is inverse of $y$ or not.

To sum up, i have some estimations but i do not know how to show this question.

Comment: I would pick a more informative title

Comment: I have taken the liberty to replace you "title" made of a concatenation of tags by a more informative one as asked by @mdave16

Comment: i am a new member of mathstacks ,that was my first question, regulation is better for title, also how can i find the element symbol ?

Comment: "is element of" is backslash followed by letters i and n.

Comment: Realted: (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/767248)

Comment: `$\in$` is $\in$

Answer (score 2):

$xH=Hy$ implies that for each $h\in H$, there exists a $k\in H$ such that $xh=ky$. Take $h=e$, the identity. Then $x=ky$ for some $k\in H$, so $xy^{-1}\in H$. So, using what you know about normal subgroups as you mention in your question, you can now show that $H$ is a normal subgroup.

Comment: Is it true am i right ? if we show y^-1x is element of H, therefore we have xHH=Hx and HH=H. Hence, xH=Hx ?

Comment: Hint: if $y^{-1}x\in H$, then what does that tell you about $y^{-1}xH$?

Comment: if we show y^-1x is element of H, therefore we have xHH=Hx and HH=H. Hence, xH=Hx ? I thought like that is it not true ? Sorry,but i did not catch the point what you mention in your comment

Comment: If $y^{-1}x\in H$, what coset is this equivalent to? ($H$ is a subgroup, so if we multiply to elements in $H$ we stay in $H$, therefore....)

Comment: $y^{-1}x\in H$ means that $xH=yH$. You should be able to use this to show what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If $xH=Hy$, then $x\in Hy$. This means that $Hx=Hy$, so while we might
not have $y=x$, we may as well assume that it is, since $xH=Hx$.